# Can you make WSL interface with windows installs?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want to use WSL for programming, but I have encountered a problem. In WSL (Ubuntu) bash, after installing Python, I need to install all my libraries again. Is there any way to make WSL python interface with my libraries on the windows python?

Comment: That could never work because it's a different platform. Native modules couldn't be loaded. It's probably best to use only WSL Python for everything.

Comment: A [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69097797/11810933) was asked a few weeks ago.  See if my answer there covers why this won't work and the best way to handle it.  It's basically just a longer version of @CherryDT's comment :-).  If you still have questions after reading that, please edit your question.  Thanks!