# ng commands always return "This: not found" on Windows WSL 2

Tags: node.js, angular, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm new on Angular, and I'm not able to run `ng` commands on WSL version 2.

I installed Angular CLI running:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After that I created a new npm project folder and a `package.json` running:

```
npm init
```

But every ng command returns:

```
/mnt/c/Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: 1: This: not found`
```

I installed Node.js on Windows with an executable (so under PowerShell, everything works as expected).  Am I wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

> I installed Node.js on Windows with an executable before (so on PowerShell works), am I wrong with this?

Not, necessarily "wrong", but it's likely part of the problem.  But you are certainly correct to question it and provide it as a critical detail in your post!

While WSL can *launch* Windows executables, keep in mind that those Windows executables (`npm` in this case) *typically* only understand Windows paths, processes, environment variables, etc.

`npm` on the Windows version of Node is a bit unusual, thought.  It provides a Bash  shell script, which is actually what is being called when you run `npm` under WSL.  That shell script was originally designed for Cygwin and Git Bash, but I see that Node recently added checks in it for WSL as well.  Before that, even (the Windows version of) `npm` itself would have issues under WSL.

But regardless of whether they've fixed `npm` to work under WSL, then you run into the next level of issues since Angular hasn't modified `ng` to detect when it is running under WSL.

Without having dug into the source code, `ng` is going to see that it is running under the Windows version of Node and try to use Windows tools and paths.  In my test under WSL (using the Windows version of Node/npm), what seems to happen is that `ng new project` tries to start `CMD.exe`.  Since it is running under the Windows version of Node, it naturally assumes that `CMD.exe` is available.

And it is, but starting `CMD.exe` from inside WSL will attempt to start in a UNC path (`\\wsl$\<distroname>\path\to\current\project\dir` or `\\wsl.localhost\...`).  CMD doesn't support UNC paths, so it defaults to the Windows directory itself, and I get:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\project'
```

While you are getting a *different* error, to be sure, it's almost certainly related to this root issue.

To make a long story longer, see my advice in the question, [How to organize programming languages and libraries in WSL and Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69097797/11810933).

To summarize it, when using development tools, either:

- Use the Windows version of the toolchain (editor, commandline, SDK, tools, etc.)
- Or use all-Linux versions of the toolchain.

Also, though, be careful with Node specifically.  You *can* install:

- The Windows version of Node for when you are using Windows tools
- The Linux version of Node for when you are using WSL tools

But when you are running in WSL/Linux, *make sure that the Linux version of `npm` and `node` appear first in the path, before the Windows version*.  This is, again, because of the fact that the Windows version provides that shell script.  If the Windows version comes before the Linux version in your Linux `PATH`, then you will continue to have issues since the Windows `npm` will get called under WSL (as it is now).

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, but I tried to run `npm run dev` on another project and it runs correctly, so I think the problem is not node different installations. Maybe bad Node installation via npm?

Comment: @MollyMillion Hmm, but your original question wasn't about a problem with `npm run dev`, but with `ng ...` commands, right?

Comment: Yes, but the error returns a Node path not found: `npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: 1: This: not found` so I thought it might have something to do with.  Moreover `npm run dev` on backend and `ng serve` on frontend work in the second project, thus the problem must not be in global installation of Angular (sorry, I forgot to add `ng serve` result in the previous comment)

Comment: @MollyMillion Hmm - Not yet sure what could cause that then.  I'll try to come back and noodle on it in a bit.  It might be good to update your question with the new information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one helped me:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/npm-command-not-found-ng

```
sudo npm install @angular/cli

npm link @angular/cli

ng n [project-name]
```